# Android - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Even though dependencies are available in the repositories  logcat showing missing.

Tried Methods:

1. clean the build
2. rebuild
3. Sync Project
4. invalidate and clear cash

gradle-wrapper.properties :
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip

Following is my code

Root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle file for the app module.

```
plugins{
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 33
 
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.name"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
//        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

       
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    defaultConfig {

        resConfigs "en", "zu"
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4071M"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.11'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.11'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:5.0.0-alpha.11'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.4.0'
implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
//implementation project(':searchablespinnerlibrary')
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.7.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:5.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
implementation('io.branch.sdk.android:library:5.6.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0'

implementation 'com.dailymotion.dailymotion-sdk-android:sdk:0.2.12'
implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:3.3.0'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.6@aar'
implementation 'com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:16.1.3'
implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.4.3'


    // Missing dependencies
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.crazysunj:cardslideview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.zplesac:connectionbuddy:2.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.0.9'
    implementation 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.1.7'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.3.1'
}
```

Logcat error received :
[image]